# In 1 John 4:18, what is the punishment of fear?

Tags: 1-john

> IJn 4:18 (asv)
>
> There is no fear in love: but perfect love casteth out fear, because fear hath punishment; and he that feareth is not made perfect in love.

Fear has punishment? What is that punishment

Comment: Also relevant to this question is Revelation 21:8 _But the fearful, and unbelieving . . . shall have their part in the lake which burneth with fire and brimstone: which is the second death._

Answer (score 3):

As with any NT book, reading the whole chapter / book helps a lot.  In this case, the preceding verse (1 John 4:17) provides the immediate meaning: **fear of the Day of Judgment**. The punishment is the same punishment that faces non believers: **Hell**.  This is NOT the fear of the Lord, which brings us to repentance and restores us to His love.

Here's the [ESV](https://www.esv.org/) translation of [1 John 4:16-18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+John+4%3A16-18&version=ESV):

> **<sup>16</sup>** So we have come to know and to believe the love that God has for us. God is love, and whoever abides in love abides in God, and God abides in him.  **<sup>17</sup>** By this is love perfected with us, so that we may have confidence for the day of judgment, because as he is so also are we in this world.  **<sup>18</sup>** There is no fear in love, but perfect love casts out fear. For fear has to do with punishment, and whoever fears has not been perfected in love.

[ESV Study Bible](https://www.crossway.org/bibles/esv-study-bible-case/) commentary on Verses 17 and 18:

> **4:17**:  **By this** refers to the previous verse, where John speaks of believers abiding in God and God abiding in them. **confidence for the day of judgment**. Either eternal life or eternal punishment awaits all humanity (see John 3:36), and God’s love furnishes a sure hope for those who have trusted in him. **as he is so also are we in this world**. Just as the Son was and is present in the world in a loving fashion that in no way attracted divine displeasure, so are the Son’s followers. The love that Christ embodied and lived out among believers is their confidence in the day of judgment.
>
> **4:18**: **No fear in love** does not rule out the presence and constructive effect of “the fear of the Lord” that is “the beginning of knowledge” (Prov. 1:7). Here John speaks of fear of final judgment (cf. 1 John 4:17). God’s **perfect love** for believers **casts out** the **fear** of wrath and eternal punishment.

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

Indeed, this is about fearing the Day of Judgment when the Lord sends brothers (“strangers”) to the churches to speak His words of life and spirit (in the Spirit of Truth) as the Son of God comes to give us an understanding (1 John 5:20) by opening up the Scriptures to our hearing ears.

This will cause a disturbance among the churches of men as it will not conform to what has been preached among them for so long. Some will hear His voice and come forth and do good (showing love) while others will come forth and do evil.

Such who will do evil will not have boldness in the Day of Judgment but will have fear instead as they will not repent of their willful sin.  Specifically, they will experience a certain fearful expectation of judgment and fiery indignation which shall devour the adversaries.   The fearful expectation is part of the punishment itself.

Our love for God is made complete ("perfect") when we show love for our brothers.

> 1 John 4:17-21 KJV (17)  ***Herein is our love made perfect, that we may
>   have boldness in the day of judgment***: because as he is, so are we in
>   this world. (18)  **There is no fear in love; but perfect love casteth
>   out fear: because fear hath torment. He that feareth is not made
>   perfect in love. (19)  We love him, because he first loved us**.

A “stranger” will come along to speak His words (speaking the Word of God in truth and sincerity) which will most likely differ than what most are currently preaching.  Some will not show love toward that brother in their unbelief of what they hear the Spirit saying to the churches.

Their love is not made "perfect"...complete.  Love for God is made complete when we show love for our brother.

> (20)  ***If a man say, I love God, and hateth his brother, he is a liar***:
>   for he that loveth not his brother whom he hath seen, how can he love
>   God whom he hath not seen? (21)  And this commandment have we from
>   him, **That he who loveth God love his brother also.**

They are warned accordingly (3 times) to remember the blood of the covenant (have brotherly love) as He loved us and gave Himself for us.   Let brotherly love continue and entertain “strangers” and their words.   He that loves God loves His brother also.

But if they insist on continuing to sin (to speak evil of their brother) after having been reminded, then there will remain no more sacrifice for their sins as their sins are now retained as their judgment is finalized.

> Hebrews 10:26-27 KJV (26)  ***For if we sin wilfully after that we have
>   received the knowledge of the truth, there remaineth no more sacrifice
>   for sins,***

Fear will grip them.  Part of the punishment is the initial fearful expectation of that final judgment impending upon them.

> (27)  ***But a certain fearful looking for of judgment and fiery
>   indignation,*** which shall devour the adversaries.

Such will have counted the blood of the covenant a common thing (unholy thing) as they will think nothing of breaking it during the Day of Judgment.   They will trodden underfoot the Son of God as they will think nothing of what He has to say nor of His sacrifice for them.    They will do despite the Spirit of grace.

> Hebrews 10:29-31 KJV (29)  *Of how much sorer punishment, suppose ye,
>   shall he be thought worthy, who hath trodden under foot the Son of
>   God, **and hath counted the blood of the covenant, wherewith he was
>   sanctified, an unholy thing,** and hath done despite unto the Spirit of
>   grace? (30)  For we know him that hath said, Vengeance belongeth unto
>   me, I will recompense, saith the Lord. **And again, The Lord shall judge
>   his people.***

It is a fearful thing to fall into the hands of the living God.  It is part of the punishment as the expectation of the Judgment itself is very fearful.

> (31)  **It is a fearful thing to fall into the hands of the living God.**

They will not receive those whom the Lord sends out to speak His words in the Holy Spirit.  They will not receive the Spirit but will continue to sin in disbelief of what He says.  The sins of those who will continue to willfully sin will be retained as the Judgment is final upon them (until they perish from off this earth).  When they are “retained”, fear will come upon them.

> John 20:21-23 KJV (21)  *Then said Jesus to them again, Peace be unto
>   you: as my Father hath sent me, even so send I you. (22)  And when he
>   had said this, he breathed on them, and saith unto them, R**eceive ye
>   the Holy Ghost: (23)  Whose soever sins ye remit, they are remitted
>   unto them; and whose soever sins ye retain, they are retained**.*

The sinners in Zion are afraid.  Fearfulness has surprised the hypocrites (those who say they love God and yet will continue to speak evil of their brothers sent by Him).

They will bring forth out of their mouth chaff and stubble (every idle word  that men will speak shall be held accountable in the Day of Judgment).  Their own breath, as fire, shall devour them. The tongue is a fire that will set on fire those will not cease from speaking evil. There will be no remedy as their judgment will be final.

> Isaiah 33:11-16 KJV (11)  ***Ye shall conceive chaff, ye shall bring
>   forth stubble: your breath, as fire, shall devour you.*** (12)  And the
>   people shall be as the burnings of lime: as thorns cut up shall they
>   be burned in the fire. (13)  Hear, ye that are far off, what I have
>   done; and, ye that are near, acknowledge my might.

Part of the Judgment is the punishment of fear within them and they will speak among themselves about the impending Judgment :  Who among us shall dwell with the devouring fire? who among us shall dwell with everlasting burnings?

> (14)  ***The sinners in Zion are afraid; fearfulness hath surprised the
>   hypocrites.*** Who among us shall dwell with the devouring fire? who
>   among us shall dwell with everlasting burnings? (15)  He that walketh
>   righteously, and speaketh uprightly; he that despiseth the gain of
>   oppressions, that shaketh his hands from holding of bribes, that
>   stoppeth his ears from hearing of blood, and shutteth his eyes from
>   seeing evil; (16)  He shall dwell on high: his place of defence shall
>   be the munitions of rocks: bread shall be given him; his waters shall
>   be sure.

Adam also feared when he heard the voice of the LORD God walking in the garden in the cool (Spirit) of the Day (which is the Day of Judgment).   Yet, Adam and his wife hid themselves from the presence of the LORD God in the tree (singular).

The lesson for today is to show love for our brothers (whom the Son of God will send out).  The Son of God comes to give us an understanding (1 John 5:20) so that we may show that we know God (and not “hide” from His presence when we hear His voice).

Those who say they love God will also love their brother. Our love is made complete.   They will bring forth fruits of righteousness and not just platitudes (“Lord, Lord”)……the sewing of fig leaves together.  There is no security in that.  A fig tree must produce fruit and not just “leaves” only.

> Genesis 3:7-12 KJV (7)  *And the eyes of them both were opened, and
>   they knew that they were naked; and they sewed fig leaves together,
>   and made themselves aprons. (8**)  And they heard the voice of the LORD
>   God walking in the garden in the cool of the day: and Adam and his
>   wife hid themselves from the presence of the LORD God** amongst the
>   trees of the garden.*

The LORD God called unto Adam and said unto him,  “Where are you?”

Where is your faith?  Faith without good works (continuing to have brotherly love) is dead.  We show we know and love God when we love our brothers also. We hide from His face when we do things that show we don't know Him (not having brotherly love).

Adam was “afraid” because he was naked.  He did not have good works to show forth his faith and instead continued to eat of the tree that they were not supposed to (continued willful sin).  They hid themselves in the tree (singular) of the knowledge of good and evil. They willfully continued to sin in the Day of Judgment and fear did take hold of them as they did not have manifest evidence of their faith...of their love for God.

> (9)  *And the LORD God called unto Adam, and said unto him, Where art
>   thou? (10)  **And he said, I heard thy voice in the garden, and I was
>   afraid, because I was naked; and I hid myself.** (11)  And he said, Who
>   told thee that thou wast naked? Hast thou eaten of the tree, whereof I
>   commanded thee that thou shouldest not eat? (12)  And the man said,
>   The woman whom thou gavest to be with me, she gave me of the tree, and
>   I did eat.*

It is the Son of God (the Beginning of the creation of God) who came to “open” their eyes as He does today.  Spoken to the church of "Laodicea" (meaning "people of the Judgment"):

> Revelation 3:15-18 KJV (15)  **I know thy works,** that thou art neither
>   cold nor hot: I would thou wert cold or hot. (16)  So then because
>   thou art lukewarm, and neither cold nor hot, I will spue thee out of
>   my mouth. (17)  Because thou sayest, I am rich, and increased with
>   goods, and have need of nothing; ***and knowest not that thou art
>   wretched, and miserable, and poor, and blind, and naked:*** (18)  I
>   counsel thee to buy of me gold tried in the fire, that thou mayest be
>   rich; and white raiment, that thou mayest be clothed, and that the
>   shame of thy nakedness do not appear; and anoint thine eyes with
>   eyesalve, that thou mayest see.

Answer (score 0):

> Luke 10:38-42 King James Version (KJV)
>
> 38 Now it came to pass, as they went, that he entered into a certain
>   village: and a certain woman named Martha received him into her house.
>   39 And she had a sister called Mary, which also sat at Jesus' feet,
>   and heard his word. 40 But Martha was cumbered about much serving, and
>   came to him, and said, Lord, dost thou not care that my sister hath
>   left me to serve alone? bid her therefore that she help me. 41 And
>   Jesus answered and said unto her, Martha, Martha, thou art careful and
>   troubled about many things: 42 But one thing is needful: and Mary hath
>   chosen that good part, which shall not be taken away from her.

Martha's sister Mary received from Jesus the mercy found in the love of the truth  and found rest in the cleansing of her conscience from hearing Christ's words by faith (faith--having an open, receptive heart). Martha was vexed sore trying to work her way through to that peace, but she did not obtain it. Jesus said she was troubled with so many things, but only one thing is needful and it will not be taken from Mary (healing mercy). Instead, Jesus vindicated Mary, and patiently corrected Martha.

The one who abides in love abides in what Mary had--knowing Jesus intimately in interactive fellowship with Him (Ro14:17;Re3:20). That love and intimacy (knowing Him) will not only give Mary and those like her confidence at time of judgment, but it eradicates fear of judgment in the present because consciousness of sin perishes in the experience of forgiveness of sin (He9:14;10:22). It is the presence of Jesus in our hearts that washes the conscience clean, and guilty fear vanishes with the renewal of innocence through His imparted righteousness (Jn7:38).

Martha learned the same way I did, from an audible correction from Jesus. It was amazing how hostile the antichrist infested church is to this one simple thought when shared with them from a grateful heart:

"It is not I who needs you, but rather it is you who needs Me."

"Yeah, but God does need you," they said with a grimace.

But God reaffirmed His prophetic word (The prophets are subject to the Prophets-- 1Co14:31):

> Hosea 6:6 King James Version (KJV)
>
> 6 For I desired mercy, and not sacrifice; and the knowledge of God
>   more than burnt offerings.

And their response to that is:

"But God *does* require sacrifice and burnt offerings (your service)."

Is that what He said? God says one thing, they say another. Always opposing Him. Always resisting. Always nullifying His word. That is their trademark.

Imagine Martha arguing with the Lord:  "*Me?* Wasn't it YOU who said we need to obey *all* your commands?" What do you think God would say to her if at that moment she negated Him with that wisecrack comment? Correcting God--what arrogance! What do you think God will do to the antichrists who persistently do?

God's not impressed with anyone "balancing" His equation with His own instruction, especially when it's out of place. Doing so is saying He is unequal.

> Ezekiel 18:29 King James Version (KJV)
>
> 29 Yet saith the house of Israel, The way of the Lord is not equal. O
>   house of Israel, are not my ways equal? are not your ways unequal?

No doctrinal balancing act can excuse Martha for her error. It just doesn't belong in the moment. It is purely evasive--an inappropriate rationalization. Martha was NOT in any condition to produce good works. She needed to hear Ho6:6 and nothing else. And so does a crowd of works consciousness naïve Christians who are in heavy bondage to deceitful leaders who could care less about perfecting them in love and only care about using them to advance their ungodly [Dominionist Kingdom Now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominion_theology) agenda.

God's mercy for you through the love of the truth (His abiding presence: Ro14:17) is the one needful thing--period, Martha, Tom. "Did we not do many wonderful works?" takes a distant second if not altogether utterly profane and useless as many will one day find out (Mt7:22-23).

The first epistle of John is written with instruction concerning recognizing false brethren, whom John referred to as antichrist deceivers professing a false gospel and idolatrous Jesus (false teaching and substitute for Jesus). These people did not have what Mary had, therefore it manifested as heretical lawlessness, hypocrisy, self righteousness and hatred toward the elect.

Knowing Jesus and loving your brethren from a clean heart bears witness to genuine sonship and the work of God in them (Mt 7:22-24;25:41-46). To the antichrist goats at the time of judgment, Jesus says, "how you treated My sheep is how you treated Me" and "I NEVER knew you".

The antichrists described by John were guilty of not having this intimacy with Christ (1Jn2:4-5) and hating the brethren (1Jn2:9-11;3:14-16). Like the Pharisees, which are forerunners of the antichrist goats (2Pe2:1), they substituted their own traditions for God's commandments; therefore, without them, they could not keep God's commandments (Man of Lawlessness, 2Th2:3;1Jn2:4-5), abide in truth or have the forgiveness of God that comes from intimate fellowship with Him (1Jn1:7, God's word is not in them so their heart is far from Him, Mt15:1-9). Not receiving the merciful healing "love of the truth" from intimacy with Christ as Martha's sister Mary had, they were turned over to the delusion created by their own wrangling of God's word (2Pe2:1;3:16) so that they might be forever damned (Son of Destruction, 2Th2:3;9-12).

The fearful awareness of punishment discussed in John's epistle must be understood in the context of antichrists as this is John's central theme. The experience of true brethren is contrasted with the behavior of false brethren to divide the two. John is trying to help them identify these deceivers by their colors so that they might overcome them with the one thing these liars didn't have: the presence of God's Spirit in them (1Jn2:27;Re12:10-11). The false teachers will never comprehend this light (Mt15:12-14;Jn9:41).

"There is a sin that leads to death," John says (1Jn5:16). Context--these antichrists were doing that very thing. That mortal sin is blaspheming the spirit by continually refusing to receive the love of the truth (Mk3:28-30,Ac7:51) which is also bearing the mark of the false prophet (Re13:15-17)--the lawlessness seen first in the corrupt Jewish religious leaders and now the same spirit of false teachers amongst Christians:

> 2 Peter 2:1 King James Version (KJV)
>
> 2 But there were false prophets also among the people (Jews), even as
>   there shall be false teachers (Man of Lawlessness, 2Th2:3) among you
>   (Christians), who privily shall bring in damnable heresies (Traditions
>   of Men), **even denying the Lord that bought them** (The Gnostic
>   antichrists--1Jn2:22), and bring upon themselves swift
>   destruction (Son of Destruction, 2Th2:3).
>
> 1 John 2:18-22 King James Version (KJV)
>
> 18 Little children, it is the last time: and as ye have heard that
>   antichrist shall come, even now are there many antichrists; whereby we
>   know that it is the last time. 19 They went out from us, but they were
>   not of us; for if they had been of us, they would no doubt have
>   continued with us: but they went out, that they might be made manifest
>   that they were not all of us....22 Who is a liar but he that denieth
>   that Jesus is the Christ? **He is antichrist, that denieth the Father
>   and the Son.**
>
> 2 Thessalonians 2:1-12 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>
> 2 Now we request you, brethren, with regard to the coming of our Lord
>   Jesus Christ and our gathering together to Him, 2 that you not be
>   quickly shaken from your composure or be disturbed either by a spirit
>   or a message or a letter as if from us, to the effect that the day of
>   the Lord has come. 3 Let no one in any way deceive you, for it will
>   not come unless the apostasy comes first, and the man of lawlessness
>   is revealed, the son of destruction, 4 who opposes and exalts himself
>   above every so-called god or object of worship, so that he takes his
>   seat in the temple of God, displaying himself as being God. 5 Do you
>   not remember that while I was still with you, I was telling you these
>   things? 6 And you know what restrains him now, so that in his time he
>   will be revealed. 7 For the mystery of lawlessness is already at work;
>   only he who now restrains will do so until he is taken out of the way.
>   8 Then that lawless one will be revealed whom the Lord will slay with
>   the breath of His mouth and bring to an end by the appearance of His
>   coming; 9 that is, the one whose coming is in accord with the activity
>   of Satan, with all power and signs and false wonders, 10 and with all
>   the deception of wickedness for those who perish, because they did not
>   receive the love of the truth so as to be saved. 11 For this reason
>   God will send upon them a deluding influence so that they will believe
>   what is false, 12 in order that they all may be judged who did not
>   believe the truth, but took pleasure in wickedness.
>
> Acts 20:29-31 New International Version (NIV)
>
> 29 I know that after I leave, savage wolves will come in among you and
>   will not spare the flock. 30 Even from your own number men will arise
>   and distort the truth in order to draw away disciples after them. 31
>   So be on your guard! Remember that for three years I never stopped
>   warning each of you night and day with tears.
>
> 1 Timothy 6:20-21 New International Version (NIV)
>
> 20 Timothy, guard what has been entrusted to your care. Turn away from
>   godless chatter and the opposing ideas of what is falsely called
>   knowledge (Gk. gnosis), 21 which some have professed and in so doing
>   have departed from the faith.

Peter, John and Paul are describing the same initial gnostic apostates, who believed recognizing their own divinity through personal enlightenment was salvation, and did not believe Jesus came in the flesh because flesh was evil. But these were only the *first* antichrists filling these last days.

And this is the sin of any antichrist apostates that damns them forever: (Mk3:28-29; 1Jo5:16-18; Re14:9-10;2Th2:8-12). These imposters simply refuse to receive what Mary received and persist in their own doctrine and works to quench that fear, obscuring the truth not only for themselves, but for others as well (Mt15:14).

As described (2Th2:8;Re14:9-10), that punishment is the destruction that comes from the brightness/glory of Christ's coming--the unrestrained glory from the face of God that will burn the tares with fire (Mt13:30). The elect who know Him will receive that day the full redemption purchased with Christ's blood--a supernatural house that will not perish in the presence of God's glory. But the imposters will suffer eternal torment in that glory because in the character of the false Jewish religious leaders who perpetually opposed Jesus, they likewise refused the love of the truth so as to be saved and were turned over to their lying religious delusions. They will find themselves tormented in their vulnerable sinful state without hope of relief.

There is the security pledge of the Holy Spirit (the earnest, Ep1:13-14) coming into our perishable house, that leads to the ultimate purchased possession (redemption, Lk21:25-28) of an imperishable house at Christ's return--a resurrection body able to stand on the day of judgment in God's unbridled glory (1Co15:50-53; Mt7:22-27). It is the love of the truth--the mercy of God from abiding in his in dwelling presence--knowing Him, that ultimately leads to the fulfillment of the promised imperishable home at the resurrection (Ac3:19-21; Ep1:13-14). Without it, the torment of the second death from the glory of God's face is inevitable.

All men are initially aware of their condition but they suppress the truth in their conscience with coping lies. God turns them over to their delusions, and their minds become dark (Ro1:18-25; 2Th2:9-12). That was manifested throughout the history of mankind with all sorts of false notions/images of who God is--pagan idolatry, Jewish idolatry and finally Christian idolatry which is 'antichrist'--refashioning the image of Christ to their own desires (Re13:14-15; 2Ti4:3-4). All substituted a lie for the truth in dealing with that awareness instructed into their conscience resulting in fear of punishment, marking themselves not with the name of the Father--The Word of God (De11:18), but with the name of their father Satan, the Father of Lies (Jn8:41-49; Re13:17;14:1). These foolish virgins buy the fake oil from their trusted shepherd merchants who sell it to appease/suppress their guilty conscience (Mt 25:8-9;Re13:17) in hope of quieting the fear of punishment that arises from it.

The punishment is simply the unbridled glory of God's presence into the fallen vessel of man whose sins contract against it causing resistance and burning torment, like a lot of electricity flowing through a thin wire creates damaging heat. (Moses was cleaner than all his people and could handle not only being on the mount with God which would have killed anyone else, but see God's backside as well. But he could still not look on God's face because he was not perfect. (Nu12:3; Ex19:12-25)

God has withdrawn most of his glory from His creation (Ro8:20-22) to protect mankind from the wrath inherent in its power and give them space to repent (2Pe3:9-10). But he will once again release His glory back into his Creation on the Day of Judgment. That brightness in His coming is His wrath. Joy to those who can handle it, torment for those who reject God's gift and are unprepared.

Consider that the fear of punishment from God's glory turned to wisdom for the Israelites who could only abandon fear of God's wrath once they repented. Initial fear of punishment is a good thing, but not if it doesn't lead to life but rather to a hardening to suppress awareness of their deserved punishment. Then that fear only reveals the absence of abiding love and mercy working in that person. (1Jn4:18)

> Exodus 20:18-20 New International Version (NIV)
>
> 18 When the people saw the thunder and lightning and heard the trumpet
>   and saw the mountain in smoke, they trembled with fear. They stayed at
>   a distance 19 and said to Moses, “Speak to us yourself and we will
>   listen. But do not have God speak to us OR WE WILL DIE.” 20 Moses said
>   to the people, “Do not be afraid. God has come to test you, so that
>   the fear of God will be with you to keep you from sinning.”
>
> Jude 22-23 King James Version (KJV)
>
> 22 And of some have compassion, making a difference: 23 And others
>   save with fear, pulling them out of the fire; hating even the garment
>   spotted by the flesh.